# Value different from what the PHP function returns

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, boolean, array-filter

I need to filter some $data array with multiple conditions.

My code:

```
public static function filterTable(array $data, $conditions) : array {
    $data = array_filter($data, function ($row) use ($conditions) {
        if ($row["check_id"] == 0) {
            var_dump(['$row'=> $row], self::validateData($row, $conditions, null, 0));
            die();
        }
        return self::validateData($row, $conditions, null, 0);
    });

    return $data;
}

public static function validateData($row, $conditions, $res, $i) : bool {
    if ($res !== null) {
        $tempRes = self::compare($row[$conditions[$i]["column"]], $conditions[$i]["value"], $conditions[$i]["condition"]);
        $res = self::logicalOp($res, $tempRes, $conditions[$i-1]["operator"]);
    } else {
        $res = self::compare($row[$conditions[$i]["column"]], $conditions[$i]["value"], $conditions[$i]["condition"]);
    }
    if (!empty($conditions[$i]["operator"])) {
        self::validateData($row, $conditions, $res, ++$i);
    }

    if ($row["check_id"] == 0) {
        var_dump(["validateDataFunc" => $row, $res]);
        die();
    }
    return $res;
}

public static function logicalOp($val1, $val2, string $op) {
    switch ($op) {
        case "||":
            return ($val1 || $val2);
        case "&&":
            return ($val1 && $val2);
        default:
            return true;
    }
}

public static function compare($val1, $val2, string $op) : bool {
    switch ($op) {
        case "=":
            return $val1 == $val2;
        case "!=":
            return $val1 != $val2;
        case ">=":
            return $val1 >= $val2;
        case "<=":
            return $val1 <= $val2;
        case ">":
            return $val1 > $val2;
        case "<":
            return $val1 < $val2;
        default:
            return true;
    }
}
```

If you output the result of the function via var_dump in the `validateData` function, then the return value is `false` (which is what you want). But, if you display the result of calling the function itself (in `filterTable` function), you get `true` at the output.

Please note that I display the result of execution for the **same array element**.

Result into `validateData` function:

```
array(2) {
  ["validateDataFunc"]=>
  array(16) {}
  [0]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Result into `filterTable` function:

```
array(1) {
  ["$row"]=>
  array(16) {}
}
bool(true)
```

I hope you'll give me some tips on how to improve my code.
Help me if u can do this, maybe I have too stupid mistake:)

Thanks

**SOLUTION:**

Add return to recursive call

```php
public static function validateData($row, $conditions, $res, $i) : bool {
        if ($res !== null) {
            $tempRes = self::compare($row[$conditions[$i]["column"]], $conditions[$i]["value"], $conditions[$i]["condition"]);
            $res = self::logicalOp($res, $tempRes, $conditions[$i-1]["operator"]);
        } else {
            $res = self::compare($row[$conditions[$i]["column"]], $conditions[$i]["value"], $conditions[$i]["condition"]);
        }
        if (!empty($conditions[$i]["operator"])) {
            return self::validateData($row, $conditions, $res, ++$i); //here
        }
        return $res;
    }
```

Comment: When you call `validateData()` recursively, you don't do anything with that result. So you're always returning the result of the original `self::compare()`, ignoring the result of the recursive call.

Comment: Change that to `$res = self::validateData(...)` or just `return self::validateData(...)`

Comment: @Barmar, I am passing the result as one of the arguments of the ```validateData()```

Comment: You're not passing it by reference, so assignment to it in the function doesn't change it.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, it helped me. If u have time can u explain more about this case or tell me how to google it to read more?

Comment: The question I linked to above doesn't explain it?

Comment: @Barmar it explains how to solve the problem, but I cant catch the logic of how it works generally. I'll explain: when I called ```var_dump``` before returning the result, the value I needed was displayed, but when I got it where I needed it, the value was the opposite. And now, when I try to understand, I can’t see the essence of why it didn’t work, although I passed the result as an argument and then worked with it. Thank you very much for the decision, but I want to have a clear understanding of my actions))

Comment: You're dumping different `$res` variables. One is in the current function, the other is in the recursive function.